# ASP.Net & JQuery Document.ready: Not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I have a master page that manually includes some javascript in the Page_Load event like so:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("site.master", ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/site.master.js"));
```

I placed $(document).ready() at the start of the script, with the expectation that it would bind properly when it was included, which it does.

The issue is that it won't fire the $(document).ready() on postback (no AJAX involved).  The solution I used was to wrap it up into an init function, and then call said init function via the master page .aspx file.  It works and isn't all that dirty, but I'm confused.

I understand the browser caches the file, but I would have expected it to still execute on every request, but it doesn't seem to be doing so.

Can someone explain why, or if I'm not seeing what I think I'm seeing, explain that as well?

I'm seeing this behavior on the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

In your Masterpage are you including JQuery before including your own JavaScript file?

This situation usually occurs when JQuery is being loaded too late in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Where were you registering these following lines?

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("site.master", ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/site.master.js"));
```

Do you conditionally register only if the current request isn't a post-back?  That would be silly.  It needs to be registered every time you need to deliver a full page.

Comment: it's being included outside the IsPostBack check.  Presumably, if that was the problem, I would have started getting a javascript error when trying to access a function defined in that file.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the postback responses to see that the script tag is included?  Do you hide the form in any way?